# Getting variable data from an Engine class isn't working in Java

Tags: java, composition

My project is composition, which a Truck HAS-A Engine which can be called using parameters into the console:

(note, engineStatus represent two arguments which would determine the parameter, IE, One or the other would be inputted; On/Off or True/False)

```
PrimaTruck truck = new PrimaTruck(150, OUColour.RED, (engineStatus));
```

I can't think how to get my second class to get the engineStatus() and insert variables properly into the constructor for use with the console command code above. My main error is that it cannot find the engineStatus variable.

I also acknowledge that my code is wrong for the Engine Boolean expressions and can't figure out a good alternative to give engineStatus() an On or Off variable dependant on if engineStart() and engineStop() are On/Off, thus giving a value that can be entered in the PrimaTrucks() constructor parameters.

**PrimaTruck.Java**

```
import ou.*;
 /**
 * Write a description of class PrimaTruck here.
 */
public class PrimaTruck{
 // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private int topSpeed;
    private OUColour colour;
    public Engine engineStatus;

  /**
  * Constructor for objects of class PrimaTruck
  * Initialise instance variables 
  */
public PrimaTruck(int topSpeed, OUColour colour, Engine engineStatus){

     this.topSpeed = topSpeed;
     this.colour = colour;
     this.engineStatus = engineStatus;
}

public void setColour(OUColour aColour){
     this.colour = aColour;
}

public OUColour getColour(){
  return colour;
}

public int getTopSpeed(){
  return topSpeed;
}
}
```

**Engine.Java**

```
/**
 * Write a description of class Engine here.
 */
public class Engine{

// instance variables
   public Boolean engineStart;
   public Boolean engineStop;
   public String engineStatus;
   private Boolean status;

/**
* Constructor for objects of class Engine
*/
public Engine(String engineStatus){

// initialise instance variables
    this.engineStart = engineStart;
    this.engineStop = engineStop;
    this.engineStatus = engineStatus;
    this.status = status;
}

public Boolean status(){    
    if (engineStart == true){
     status = engineStart;
    }else if (engineStop = true){;
     status = engineStop;
  }
     return this.status;
}

public Boolean getEngineStart(){
     return engineStart; 
}

public void setEngineStart(){
     this.engineStop = false;
     this.engineStart = true;
}

public Boolean getEngineStop(){
     return engineStop; 
}

public void setEngineStop(){
     this.engineStart = false;
     this.engineStop = true;
}

public void setEngineStatus(String aStatus){
     this.engineStatus = aStatus;
} 

public String getEngineStatus(){
     return engineStatus;
}
}
```

Any feedback on coding or pointers on how to implement will be appreciated.

Comment: where is your engine class? `public PrimaTruck(int topSpeed, OUColour colour, Engine engineStatus)` should be something like `public PrimaTruck(int topSpeed, OUColour colour, boolean engineStatus)` so the true/false will work properly.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I believe it was accidentally omitted judging from the "Engine.java" text at the bottom

Comment: @OP: "it cannot find a variable True" explain further?

Comment: @BrettRoberts You can't assign a value of `true` or `false` to an `Engine` reference. On a side note, why does `getEngineStatus` call itself recursively?

Comment: @CKing I suspect it's meant to be `return engineStatus.getEngineStatus();` ...

Comment: Sorry, updated form, pressed Enter by accident upon writing. Please check again.

Comment: The constructor for Engine class is wrong. It should have 4 parameters. But only 1 is there.

Comment: Agreed: changed to Engine(Boolean engineStart, Boolean engineStop, String engineStatus, Boolean status)

Comment: to create a primatruck at the current code state call something like this:`PrimaTruck truck = new PrimaTruck(150, OUColour.RED, new Engine(flase,true,"idk what goes here",true));`. you should really think about your variable naming. enginestatus is once a string and should once be an boolean. this makes it very hard to understand it properly. should the enginestatus in primatruck be the status in engine?

Comment: That makes sense. I apologise i'm relatively new to Java. the `engineStatus` in `PrimaTruck` constructor ideally wants to fetch wether the engine is On or Off from the `Engine` class. I imagine a re-write of the whole engine class is in order to achieve this.   the end goal would be to get the call to be: `PrimaTruck truck = new PrimaTruck(150, OUColour.RED, On/Off);` <-- ON/OFF proberly by String instead of Boolean values.

Comment: then you should replace the variables in engine class with simply 1 variable. id call it `engineRunning`. you can take this as boolean. true means its running. 

i  dont completely understand the fetching you want to achieve. if you set the engine status at initializing, the is nothing to fetch anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of the code in the Engine class seems redundant. I'm making lot of changes to the code. See whether this is what you want.

```
public class Engine{

// instance variables
public boolean engineStart;
public boolean engineStop;
public boolean engineStatus;

/**
* Constructor for objects of class Engine
*@param1 - true if engine is started
*@param2 - true if engine is stopped
*@param3 - true if engine is on, else false
*/
public Engine(boolean engineStart, boolean engineStop, boolean engineStatus){

// initialise instance variables
this.engineStart = engineStart;
this.engineStop = engineStop;
this.engineStatus = engineStatus;

}

public boolean getEngineStart(){
     return engineStart; 
}

public void setEngineStart(){
 this.engineStop = false;
 this.engineStart = true;
 setEngineStatus(true);
}

public boolean getEngineStop(){
 return engineStop; 
}

public void setEngineStop(){
 this.engineStart = false;
 this.engineStop = true;
 setEngineStatus(false);
}

public void setEngineStatus(boolean engineStatus){

 this.engineStatus = engineStatus;

} 

public String getEngineStatus(){
 return engineStatus;
}
}
```

This Engine class has only 3 boolean variables: engineStart, engineStop, engineStatus. If engineStart = true, then engineStatus = true. Else engineStatus = false.

I hope this is the functionality you are trying to achieve. Now you need to pass in 3 boolean variables while creating an Engine object.

Now in the truck class make the following changes:

```
public class PrimaTruck{
// instance variables - replace the example below with your own
private int topSpeed;
private OUColour colour;
public boolean engineStatus;

/**
* Constructor for objects of class PrimaTruck
* Initialise instance variables 
*/
public PrimaTruck(int topSpeed, OUColour colour, Engine engine){

 this.topSpeed = topSpeed;
 this.colour = colour;
 this.engineStatus = engine.getEngineStatus();
}
```

If this is not what you were looking for, feel free to ask in comments.

Comment: `engine.getEngineStatus();` should result in an NPE because you never initialize the engine. `engine.getEngineStatus();` would be `engineStatus.getEngineStatus();` but this wouldnt make sense too because you would have to initilaize the engine in the truck constructor

Comment: from your code, im getting a compiling error of `Cannot find symbol - Variable engineStatus` .. This is the functionality I am after though!

Comment: I've just changed the variable name in my code, because engine is more apt compared to engineStatus. See my initialization.

Comment: check now... and the variable engineStatus should be a boolean

Comment: `public String getEngineStatus(){ return engineStatus;}` brings back variable error but replacing with boolean seems to compile with no syntax.  What would be the method of calling this from  `PrimaTruck truck = new PrimaTruck(150, OUColour.RED, (engine.?) ); ` as i've tried different possibilities with no display outcome.

Comment: you need to pass an Engine object which was already created. Let me give an example: Engine e1 = new Engine(true, false, true); PrimaTruck truck = new PrimaTruck(150, OUColour.RED, e1 );

Comment: Ah yes, of course. Can't believe I overlooked initialising an object. This will all help towards my project and thanks for your time. :) +accepted.

Comment: happy to have helped you. I would be more happy if you upvote my answer :)